# Como correr una aplicacion docker en Linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, .net, docker, docker-machine

Tengo una aplicación ASP.NET (modelo - vista - controlador) que he dockerizado en Windows. Lo que quiero hacer es enviarla a una máquina Linux (por el momento es una WLS, pero me gustaría enviarlo a un servidor). He encontrado la forma de compilar programas .NET en Windows siguiendo las instrucciones [de su página](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian):

```
dotnet run
```

Ejecutando el comando anterior dentro de la carpeta del proyecto previamente copiado (del proyecto .NET original de Windows a la máquina Linux). El caso es que en mi máquina Windows ejecuto la aplicación dockerizada a través de las funcionalidades de Visual Studio (básicamente, apretar un botón), pero en la máquina Linux lo tengo que hacer desde la línea de comandos, pero no sé cómo ejecutar el contenedor en el terminal de Linux.

¿Entonces, cómo puedo enviar una aplicación .NET contenida en un Docker a una máquina Linux y ejecutarla desde allí?

Gracias por todo

)

Comment: Te estás confundiendo, utilizar Docker es una cosa y tener la instalación de dotnet en el Linux es otra, esto último es lo que estás siguiendo con la documentación que mencionas. Revisa este enlace: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows El tema es extenso, saludos.

Comment: Ya vi cómo hacerlo!! Gracias por la ayuda, me encallé varios dias por no leer bien la documentación, error de novato :(
La página de ayuda: [Building NET docker images](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-6.0#run-in-a-linux-container-or-windows-container). Los comandos que usé: `docker build -t aspnetapp .` y `docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name aspnetcore_sample aspnetapp`. Muchas gracias !

Comment: Sí, docker es docker, por algo se ha estandarizado en la industria. Relax, entre todos aprendemos, por otro lado, en la parte inferior de tu pregunta hay una caja de area de texto que dice "Tu Respuesta", coloca ahí los pasos que has seguido para darle solución a tu pregunta, luego de 24 horas recuerda marcarla como aceptada para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad, encontré cómo hacerlo (partiendo de tener una aplicación .NET ya dockerizada en Windows y trasladada a un entorno Linux).

En la màquina Linux, dentro del directorio de la aplicación, ejecute:

```
docker build -t nombre_docker .
```

Para compilar la aplicación en Docker y crear una imagen de nombre *nombre_docker*, recuerde que es Key Sensitive y que el nombre que quiera poner debe ir en minúsculas. El comando busca el archivo *Dockerfile* en el directorio especificado (en este caso, el actual). Compruebe que exista antes de ejecutar el comando.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name nombre_contenedor nombre_docker
```

Para ejecutar la aplicación Docker. El comando elimina automáticamente el contenedor cuándo se cierre y asigna el puerto 5000 de la màquina local al puerto 80 del contenedor, y le da a este el nombre *nombre_contenedor*. El contenedor creado se asigna a la imagen *nombre_docker*.